# Using JQuery - on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

So... I made a page where you can find some products, and each product has a price/description/title. I’m currently trying to change prices, but the thing is I want them to change if you click on a button (which is sales related). I’d like to change the price and add a 20% discount.

I started to do something, which only change the color of the prices from black to red:

```
$(".row a").click(function(){
  $("cat-bonnet").css("color","red");
});
```

I selected the class of my thing through CSS. But now I don’t know how I am supposed to add the discount. Should I create another code ? How can You do it when clicking on a button ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is cat-bonnet meant to be a class or an element? If it's a class you're missing a .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is often best to provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Basically, the amount of code you have provided is not enough to be able to offer proper help.

Comment: I think if you have mutiple products than what ever logic you are applied , apply on all prices if you directly use class.

Comment: Thanks for your remark, I'll change it !

Answer (score 0):

`$("cat-bonnet")` would try to target `<cat-bonnet></cat-bonnet>` in the DOM.

You must specify that it's:
A class
`$(".cat-bonnet")`
Or an ID:
`$("#cat-bonnet")`

Answer (score 0):

Specify the `class` or the `id` of `cat-bonnet` by using `.` for a class or a `#` for id:

```js
$(".row a").click(function(e){
  $(".cat-bonnet").css("color","red"); // Add '.' here
  e.preventDefault(); // stop page from redirecting (to see change effect)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <a class="cat-bonnet" href="https://www.google.com">Link</a>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it's fairly easily done with a piece of vanilla javascript:

```
document.querySelector(".cat-bonnet").innerHTML = newPrice;
```

newPrice should be your calculated discount. So you should get the price of `.cat-bonnet` and calculate the 20% discount. This could be done in a variable `let = newPrice;` or inline.

*Jquery is a large library and based on your code above you may be better of with just vanilla javascript. But just adding the above line will do the trick for you.*

Comment: Op already have Jquery tag and code..this saw he already use it.

Comment: Good point, @mukeshkudi 

But the problem with the above code is that you load a whole javascript library just to change a price and a colour of a html element.

Firing a function with `onclick="function()" and changing the innerHTML and style.color of the element will do the trick without loading a complete framework.

Comment: How does you know that he does not use Jquery all over the code or not ?
he just posy a piece of code...right ?

Comment: You're right, he indeed posted a small amount of code. Based on that small amount I answered. If he uses jQuery a lot than it is ofcourse no problem at all. The above line of code will still work, but could be optimized for Jquery ofcourse.

Comment: I just don't understand how could I implement the discount with what you said. Can I integrate it into my code or should I put it on another line ?

Comment: Well you should integrate it in your code on a different line.

Answer (score 0):

What does `add discount` do?
Does it post data to apu endpoint? Or just change the html? Or any other processes?

Comment: In fact I want to click on the sales button and immediately change prices, so previous prices should disappear when clicking

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a slightly different setup to your code to make it easier to add more properties if you wish to in future. I've also put down a way to check for various ON actions such as `'mouseenter'`, `'mouseleave'` etc.

Have a look at the code below. I think this will make it a lot easier to read when your projects get bigger.

```js
$(".row a").on('click', () => { // Insert mouseenter, mouseleave etc where click is
  $(".cat-bonnet").css({
  color: "red",
  backgroundColor: "gray"
  // Add more properties inside the object here as you wish
  }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <a class="cat-bonnet" href="https://www.google.com">Link</a>  
</div>
```